# Cannot Determine Location In Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2, mapactivity

I am trying to create Android where showing the user's location in Map-view.But when run this app it says "Can't Determinate Location" .I am in stuck .Can you help me with my code or a link to a guide on how to implement this correctly?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyMapLocationActivity extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // main.xml contains a MapView
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    // extract MapView from layout
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    // create an overlay that shows our current location
    myLocationOverlay = new FixedMyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

    // add this overlay to the MapView and refresh it
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
    mapView.postInvalidate();

    // call convenience method that zooms map on our location
    zoomToMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // when our activity resumes, we want to register for location updates
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // when our activity pauses, we want to remove listening for location updates
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
}

/**
 * This method zooms to the user's location with a zoom level of 10.
 */
private void zoomToMyLocation() {
    GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
    if(myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationGeoPoint);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(10);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot determine location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}}
```

FixedMyLocationOverlay.java

```
public class FixedMyLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

private boolean bugged = false;

private Drawable drawable;
private Paint accuracyPaint;
private Point center;
private Point left;
private int width;
private int height;

public FixedMyLocationOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
    super(context, mapView);
}

@Override
protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
        Location lastFix, GeoPoint myLocation, long when) {
    if(!bugged) {
        try {
            super.drawMyLocation(canvas, mapView, lastFix, myLocation, when);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // we found a buggy phone, draw the location icons ourselves
            bugged = true;
        }
    }

    if(bugged) {
        if(drawable == null) {

            accuracyPaint = new Paint();
            accuracyPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            accuracyPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);

            drawable = mapView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_maps_indicator_current_position);
            width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            center = new Point();
            left = new Point();
        }

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        double latitude = lastFix.getLatitude();
        double longitude = lastFix.getLongitude();
        float accuracy = lastFix.getAccuracy();

        float[] result = new float[1];

        Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, latitude, longitude + 1, result);
        float longitudeLineDistance = result[0];

        GeoPoint leftGeo = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1e6), (int)((longitude-accuracy/longitudeLineDistance)*1e6));
        projection.toPixels(leftGeo, left);
        projection.toPixels(myLocation, center);
        int radius = center.x - left.x;

        accuracyPaint.setColor(0xff6666ff);
        accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

        accuracyPaint.setColor(0x186666ff);
        accuracyPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, accuracyPaint);

        drawable.setBounds(center.x - width/2, center.y - height/2, center.x + width/2, center.y + height/2);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}}
```

In manifest file i add below this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running app in emulator or device?

Comment: @MysticMagic No . Using real device

Comment: @MysticMagic Can you identify where is error ?

Comment: Unfortunately, No :/ sorry.

Comment: @MysticMagic No Problem . I am new in android that's why i face this. Trying to overcome .Many thanks for response my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link could be useful, it worked for me:

http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2013/06/google-maps-android-api-v2-showing.html

The above link explains 2 things,

1. How to implement Google map version 2 in Android.
2. How to implement location listener to determine user location.

The overall code shows how to get your current location using NETWORK_PROVIDER and display it by a marker on Google map. Your device need to have Google map installed and internet connection to run properly. The below code is the most important part to determine user location when he changes his position:

```
@Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   map.clear();

   MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

   mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

   mp.title("my position");

   map.addMarker(mp);

   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

  }
```